# How to fetch data and display on the list according many value must display from temporary value

Tags: android, json, if-statement, for-loop

I'm trying to display data from a database. I was able to do it, but I don't know how to only fetch data according the values I have. For example:

I have a value `a = 5;` then data to display will be : `data1`, `data2`, `data3`, `data4`, `data5` (< display 5 data).

But I don't know how to do that. Any help is appreciated.
Here is my code:

```
//Temporary Value     
final double a =  Math.floor(Double.parseDouble(transportResultA) / 10);
final double b =  Math.floor(Double.parseDouble(transportResultB)/10);
final double c =  Math.floor(Double.parseDouble(transportResultC)/10);
```

Fetch data code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < response.length() ; i++) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                    Exercise exercise = new Exercise();
                                    if (obj.getString("KindOf").equals(textKindOF.getText().toString()) && obj.getString("Type").equals("Cardio")) {
                                            exercise.setTipe(obj.getString("KindOf"));
                                            exercise.setJenis(obj.getString("Type"));
                                            exercise.setMainmuscle(obj.getString("Name"));
                                        exerciseList.add(exercise);

                                   }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
```

If I change how many data I want to fetch, I change `response.length()` to a data success only 5 data, but when I try to change `obj.getString("Type").equals("Cardio")` with other type like `obj.getString("Type").equals("Strength")` data didn't display. What seems to be wrong with my code?

JSON STRING

```
{
  "KindOf": "Leg",
  "Type": "Cardio",
  "Name": "Cardio1",
},
{
  "KindOf": "Leg",
  "Type": "Cardio",
  "Name": "Cardio2",
},
{
  "KindOf": "Leg",
  "Type": "Cardio",
  "Name": "Cardio3",
},
{
  "KindOf": "Leg",
  "Type": "Cardio",
  "Name": "Cardio4",
},
{
  "KindOf": "Leg",
  "Type": "Cardio",
  "Name": "Cardio5",
},
{
  "KindOf": "Leg",
  "Type": "Strength",
  "Name": "Strength1",
},
{
  "KindOf": "Leg",
  "Type": "Strength",
  "Name": "Strength2",
},
{
  "KindOf": "Leg",
  "Type": "Strength",
  "Name": "Strength3",
},
{
  "KindOf": "Leg",
  "Type": "Strength",
  "Name": "Strength4",
},
{
  "KindOf": "Leg",
  "Type": "Strength",
  "Name": "Strength5",
};
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of the whole JSON?

Comment: please give your json string.

Comment: Update Example my JSON String

Comment: Your JSON should be a JSONArray. Try to change the structure of your JSON.

Comment: i think alreayd array for json to fetct all data looks on my code, prolem is when i change `response.length()` wtih value only `type cardio` will fetch, but  for another type cannot be displayed